# Global var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is annoying me.

I'm setting an array in beginning of the doc:

```
 var idPartner;

 var myar = new Array();
 myar[0] = "http://example.com/"+idPartner;
```

And I'm getting a number over the address, which is the id of partner. Great. But I'm trying to set it without success:

```
 $.address.change(function(event) {
   idPartner = 3;
   alert(idPartner);
 }
```

Ok. The alert is giving me the right number, but isn't setting it.

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you try reproducting the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Use `[]` literal notation instead of `new Array`. (It won't solve this particular problem but is better anyway).

Comment: How is it alerting the right number, but not setting it?

Comment: @Lucas Veiga I will suggest to start using "var myar = [];" for arrays.

Comment: if the alert gives you the right number then it has been set! i'm confused. why do you think it isnt set?

Comment: Cause im trying to access the url set on myar[0] with the id, but isnt working. It gives me undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the value of the variable does not re-set the values within the array. That is just something javascript can't do automatically. You would have to re-generate the array for it to have the new id. Could you add the id to the value where you use the array instead of pre-setting the values in the array containing the id?

Edit: For example, you would do:

```
var myArray = [];
var myId = 0;
myArray[0] = "http://foo.com/id/";
```

and when you need to use a value from the array, you would do this:

```
var theVal = myArray[0] + myId;
```

Comment: Back in the day ALGOL had a pass-by-name option that allowed this kind of stuff to be done. Weird, uh?

Comment: Great. Was it. I created a function to set it for me with the id what i want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myvar = ["http://site.com/"];


$.address.change(function(event) {
   myvar[1] = 3;
 }
```

then use myvar.join ()  where you need the full url.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that at the line

```
myar[0] = "http://site.com/"+idPartner;
```

..you perform a string concatenation, meaning you *copy* the resulting string into the array at index position 0.

Hence, when later setting `idPartner`it won't have any effect on the previously *copied* string. To avoid such effect you can either always construct the string again when the `idPartner`variable updates or you create an object and you evaluate it when you need it like...

```
var MyObject = function(){
   this.idPartner = 0; //default value
};

MyObject.prototype.getUrl = function(){
   return "http://site.com/" + this.idPartner;
};
```

In this way you could use it like

```
var myGlblUrlObj = new MyObject();

$.address.change(function(event){
   myGlblUrlObj.idPartner = ... /setting it here
});
```

at some later point you can then always get the correct url using

```
myGlblUrlObj.getUrl();
```

Now obviously it depends on the complexity of your situation. Maybe the suggested array solution might work as well, although I prefer having it encapsulated somewhere in an object for better reusability.

Answer (score 0):

```
myar[0] = "http://site.com/" + idPartner;
```

After this line, `myar[0] = "http://site.com/undefined"` and it has nothing to do with the variable `idPartner` no more.

So, after that changing the value of `idPartner` will affect the value of `myar[0]`.

You need to change the value of `myar[0]` itself.